# Excluding some character from a range - javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

To validate only word simplest regex would be (I think)

```
/^\w+$/
```

I want to exclude digits and `_` from this (as it accept `aa10aa`and aa_aa now, I want to reject them)

I think it can be gained by

```
 /^[a-zA-z]+$/
```

which means I have to take a different approach other than the previous one.

but what if I want to exclude any character from this range 
suppose I will not allow `k`,`K`,`p`,`P` or more.

**Is there a way to add an excluding list in the range without changing the range.?**

Comment: good question.. anybody with good answer pls share

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To exclude `k` or `p` from `[a-zA-Z]` you need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
(?![kpKP])[a-zA-Z]+
```

Use anchors if necessary.

```
^(?:(?![kpKP])[a-zA-Z])+$
```

It checks for not of `k` or `p` before matching each character.

OR

```
^(?!.*[kpKP])[a-zA-Z]+$
```

It just excludes the lines which contains `k` or `p` and matches only those lines which contains only alphabets other than `k` or `p`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM2sY2/1)

Answer (score 7):

```
^(?!.*(?:p|k))[a-zA-Z]+$
```

This should do it.See demo.The negative lookahead will assert that matching word has no `p` or `k`.Use `i` modifier as well.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/31

```
var re = /^(?!.*(?:p|k))[a-zA-Z]+$/gmi;
var str = 'One\nTwo\n\nFour\nFourp\nFourk';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: @Saif the answer you accepted is same as mine and was posted after me :)

Comment: Great answer, I tried it once and it worked! I need to deal with a very complex code generation at hand, thank you!